# Rhino Mocks exception "Expected #1, Actual #0" in apparently working code

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have a piece of code from an old book on MVVM which works, but a test using Rhino Mocks fails with this message:

> Test method TestProject.UnitTest1.UpdateCustomer_Always_CallsUpdateWithCustomer threw exception: 
>       Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException: DataProvider.DoSomething(ConsoleApp.Customer); Expected #1, Actual #0

I'm providing an example which I think is equivalent:

```
namespace ConsoleApp {
    class Program { static void Main () { } }

    public class Customer { public string ID { get; set; } }

    public class DataProvider {
        public virtual Customer GetCustomer (string id) => new Customer ();
        public virtual void DoSomething (Customer customer) { }
    }

    public class ViewModel {
        DataProvider _dataProvider;
        Customer _customer;

        public ViewModel (DataProvider dataProvider, string id) {
            _dataProvider = dataProvider;
            _customer = new Customer { ID = id };
        }

        public void DoSomething () => _dataProvider.DoSomething (_customer);
    }
}
```

and the test that fails

```
namespace TestProject {
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1 {
        [TestMethod]
        public void UpdateCustomer_Always_CallsUpdateWithCustomer () {
            DataProvider dataProviderMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<DataProvider> ();
            Customer expectedCustomer = new Customer ();
            dataProviderMock.Stub (u => u.GetCustomer (Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return (expectedCustomer);
            ViewModel target = new ViewModel (dataProviderMock, string.Empty);
            target.DoSomething ();
            dataProviderMock.AssertWasCalled (d => d.DoSomething (expectedCustomer));
        }
    }
}
```

I read several posts on this result, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/369777/774575) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23507684/774575), but this doesn't help me. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55123368/774575) which seems interesting:

> I usually get this error when a stubbed method is called with an object argument 
>   that I build in the test and in the tested code the object is built before calling that method.

While this could be a reason for the Rhino Mocks to fail, it seems to be a bug.

My question is: Is there something wrong in my test and there is a bug in Rhino Mocks, or is there a problem with my code?

Comment: You may want to provide [MCVE]... it is very hard to see what is happening overall with just bits of code shown.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: You're right, done.

Comment: @mins your example view model does not invoke `DataProvider.GetCustomer`. it is using the one initialized in the constructor. Thus the exception thrown by the test is accurate given the shown example.

Comment: "the test just checks DataProvider.DoSomething is called with *some object*" is not what code in the post shows to my knowledge... it is rather "`DoSomething` is called with exactly the `expectedCustomer`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test stubs `DataProvider.GetCustomer` to return an expected customer instance to be used in the assertion, but the example view model does not invoke `DataProvider.GetCustomer`.

It is using the one initialized in the constructor.

```
//...

public ViewModel (DataProvider dataProvider, string id) {
    _dataProvider = dataProvider;
    _customer = new Customer { ID = id };
}

//...
```

Thus the exception thrown by the test is accurate given the shown example.

That is because the actual instance used by the view model will not be the one used in the assertion when the test is exercised.

```
//...

dataProviderMock.AssertWasCalled (d => d.DoSomething (expectedCustomer));
```

In order for the test to behave as expected based on its arrangement the view model would actually have be refactored to decouple from initializing the `Customer`

For example

```
public class ViewModel {
    DataProvider _dataProvider;
    string id;

    public ViewModel (DataProvider dataProvider, string id) {
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void DoSomething () {
        Customer customer = _dataProvider.GetCustomer(id);
        _dataProvider.DoSomething (_customer);
    }
}
```

The test should also be more explicit about what it is trying to test

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdateCustomer_Always_CallsUpdateWithCustomer () {
        //Arrange
        DataProvider dataProviderMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<DataProvider> ();
        string id = "FakeId";
        Customer expectedCustomer = new Customer { ID = id };
        dataProviderMock.Stub (u => u.GetCustomer (id))
            .Return (expectedCustomer);
        ViewModel target = new ViewModel (dataProviderMock, id);

        //Act
        target.DoSomething ();

        //Assert
        dataProviderMock.AssertWasCalled (d => d.DoSomething (expectedCustomer));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the view model is as intended then the test needs to assert its expectations differently

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdateCustomer_Always_CallsUpdateWithCustomer () {
        //Arrange
        DataProvider dataProviderMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<DataProvider> ();
        string id = "FakeId";            
        ViewModel target = new ViewModel (dataProviderMock, id);

        //Act
        target.DoSomething ();

        //Assert
        dataProviderMock
            .AssertWasCalled (d => d.DoSomething (Arg<Customer>.Matches(c => c.ID == id));
    }
}
```

Note the delegate used in the assertion to verify the characteristics of the expected argument instead of the specific instance passed when it was invoked.

Comment: "*The example view model does not invoke DataProvider.GetCustomer. It is using the one initialized in the constructor*" `DataProvider.GetCustomer` is overriden by the mock to return it's own object: `dataProviderMock.Stub (u => u.GetCustomer (Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return (expectedCustomer)`. I can update my example, but that won't change the error (i may be wrong).

Comment: @mins in your example `GetCustomer` is never used. You are manually creating the instance in the viewmodel constructor.

Comment: You're answer is correct given my question, so I accept it. The erroneous code in my question isn't representative of the code producing the error, so the answer can't be reused. I'll post a new question if I can simplify my code in a good sample.

Comment: @mins understood. Try to make sure that your example accurately represents the **actual** problem.